# Guice and URLRewrite filter integration

Tags: java, servlets, guice, tuckey-urlrewrite-filter, guice-servlet

I'm incrementally migrating our application servlets from web.xml to Guice servlet module and encountered problem with UrlRewrite filter (tuckey.org/urlrewrite/‎). It does not process servlets registered in Guice module. If I register both servlet and filter in web.xml everything works fine, but If I try to register them in Guice module - doesnt. 
Has someone encountered similar problem ?

Here are some excerpts from code :

1) Guice configuration module.

```
public class ServletConfigurationModule extends ServletModule {

@Override
protected void configureServlets() {

    bind(UrlRewriteFilter.class).in(Singleton.class);

    Map<String, String> urlRewriteParams = new HashMap<>();
    urlRewriteParams.put("confReloadCheckInterval", "60");
    urlRewriteParams.put("statusEnabled", "false");

    filter("/*").through(UrlRewriteFilter.class, urlRewriteParams);

    serve("/account").with(Account.class);
```

2) urlrewrite.xml contents

```
    <rule>
       <from>/affiliate-activation</from>
       <to>/account?do=affiliate&amp;trg=5</to>
    </rule>
```

When I try to open url myhost/affiliate-activation I get 404 HTTP error.

Comment: I suppose that posting sample code is always welcome and enables better understanding of the problem.

Comment: Everything seems perfectly fine. I'm afraid that this filter may simply won't work with guice.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I've worked this out. [Here](https://github.com/Opalo/stackoverflow/tree/master/tuckey) You can find a repo with an example. Clone the repo and execute `gradle jettyRun`. You can test the application with browser. Feel free to ask any questions and share ideas. Basically the `urlrewrite.xml` was changed.

Comment: Hi, thanks for Your help, the solution worked, but is there any way to not overwrite the original (in our case "affiliate-activation") URL with redirected URL (/account?do=affiliate&trg=5) in browser ? In other words the original URL should stay the same in browser window.